# Construct a sequence of time related names

Tags: scala

We have the following sequence in our code:

`val halfHourlyColumnNames = Seq("t0000", "t0030", "t0100", "t0130", "t0200", "t0230", "t0300", "t0330", "t0400", "t0430", "t0500", "t0530", "t0600", "t0630", "t0700", "t0730", "t0800", "t0830", "t0900", "t0930", "t1000", "t1030", "t1100", "t1130", "t1200", "t1230", "t1300", "t1330", "t1400", "t1430", "t1500", "t1530", "t1600", "t1630", "t1700", "t1730", "t1800", "t1830", "t1900", "t1930", "t2000", "t2030", "t2100", "t2130", "t2200", "t2230", "t2300", "t2330")`

I would like to rewrite this in a much more concise way. What would be the shortest way to create the above sequence in Scala?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go:

```
scala> (0 to 23).flatMap( h => List(0,30).map( m => "t%02d%02d".format(h,m) ))
res8: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(
t0000, t0030, t0100, t0130, t0200, t0230, t0300, t0330, t0400, t0430, t0500,
t0530, t0600, t0630, t0700, t0730, t0800, t0830, t0900, t0930, t1000, t1030,
t1100, t1130, t1200, t1230, t1300, t1330, t1400, t1430, t1500, t1530, t1600,
t1630, t1700, t1730, t1800, t1830, t1900, t1930, t2000, t2030, t2100, t2130,
t2200, t2230, t2300, t2330)
```

Using Scala 2.10: `for` comprehension and string interpolation with formatting:

```
scala> for( h <- 0 to 23; m <- Seq(0,30)) yield f"t$h%02d$m%02d"
res6: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(
  t0000, t0030, t0100, t0130, t0200, t0230, t0300, t0330, t0400, t0430, t0500, 
  t0530, t0600, t0630, t0700, t0730, t0800, t0830, t0900, t0930, t1000, t1030,
  t1100, t1130, t1200, t1230, t1300, t1330, t1400, t1430, t1500, t1530, t1600, 
  t1630, t1700, t1730, t1800, t1830, t1900, t1930, t2000, t2030, t2100, t2130, 
  t2200, t2230, t2300, t2330)
```

Answer (score 16):

For comprehensions is more demonstrative for Cartesian product

```
 scala> for {
         | hour <- 0 to 23
         | minutes <- List(0, 30)
         | } yield "t%02d%02d".format(hour, minutes)
    res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(t0000, t0030, t0100, t0130, t0200, t0230, t0300, t0330, t0400, t0430, t0500, t0530, t0600, t0630, t0700, t0730, t0800, t0830, t0900, t0930, t1000, t1030, t1100, t1130, t1200, t1230, t1300, t1330, t1400, t1430, t1500, t1530, t1600, t1630, t1700, t1730, t1800, t1830, t1900, t1930, t2000, t2030, t2100, t2130, t2200, t2230, t2300, t2330)
```

Comment: I very much like this version but I have marked @tuxdna's response as the correct one because it's shorter and I was asking for the shortest way.

Comment: @joscas The two solutions are exactly the same, as the for comprehension translates directly to the `flatMap` and `map` solution. This could fit on one line just the same. In fact, I would say this solution is somewhat more readable in this format.

Answer (score 8):

The shortest way I know of to do this is with string interpolation and using division and modulus to get the 30s:

```
(0 to 47).map(i => f"t${i/2}%02d${30*(i%2)}%02d")
```

Answer (score 4):

A variation:

```
for { time <- 0 to 47 }
    yield "t%02d%02d".format(time/2, (if( time % 2 == 0) 0 else 30))

res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = 
Vector(t0000, t0030, t0100, t0130, t0200, t0230, t0300, t0330, t0400, t0430, t0500, 
t0530, t0600, t0630, t0700, t0730, t0800, t0830, t0900, t0930, t1000, t1030, t1100,
t1130, t1200, t1230, t1300, t1330, t1400, t1430, t1500, t1530, t1600, t1630, t1700,
t1730, t1800, t1830, t1900, t1930, t2000, t2030, t2100, t2130, t2200, t2230, t2300, 
t2330)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun ..

```
scala> (0 to 2330).map(x => f"t$x%04d").filter(_.matches(".*(00|30)$"))
res20: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(t0000, t0030, t0100, t0130, t0200,    
t0230, t0300, t0330, t0400, t0430, t0500, t0530, t0600, t0630,t0700, t0730, t0800, t0830, t0900,
t0930, t1000, t1030, t1100, t1130, t1200, t1230, t1300, t1330, t1400, t1430, t1500, t1530, t1600,     
t1630, t1700, t1730, t1800, t1830, t1900, t1930, t2000, t2030, t2100, t2130, t2200, t2230, t2300,t2330)
```

Comment: Nice one too. A bit convoluted though :-)

Comment: Yeah, I may never use it but it was fun :)